# Unable to discriminate template specialization with enable_if and is_base_of

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I am trying to trade some run-time checks for compile-time checks to identify the base class of an object with template specializations.

The code compiles fine, but I can't figure out why the `enable_if` statement always end up invalid or equal to `void` because I'm always landing on the base template struct.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct BaseOne {};
struct DerivedOne : BaseOne {};
struct BaseTwo {};
struct DerivedTwo : BaseTwo {};
struct Default {};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct get_category_impl {
    static constexpr int value = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct get_category_impl<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<BaseOne, T>::value, T>::type> {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

template<typename T>
struct get_category_impl<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<BaseTwo, T>::value, T>::type> {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr int get_category = get_category_impl<T>::value;

int main() {
    cout << get_category<BaseOne>    << "\n"; // prints 0
    cout << get_category<DerivedOne> << "\n"; // prints 0
    cout << get_category<BaseTwo>    << "\n"; // prints 0
    cout << get_category<DerivedTwo> << "\n"; // prints 0
    cout << get_category<Default>    << "\n"; // prints 0
}
```

Comment: The code as provided does not compile. You're missing required includes and `std::` prefixes all over the place.

Comment: I excluded them from the sample to save some space. I'll edit to add them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to `enable_if` doesn't need to be specified. If you do specify it, it needs to somehow resolve to `void`. Since you've specified the second parameter as `T`, this doesn't work.

Instead, just do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct get_category_impl<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<BaseOne, T>::value>::type> {
                                                                         // ^  No T 
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};
```

and similarly for the other specialization.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G6Ennz).